# Caching when consuming a webservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let’s say I have a weather web service that I’m hitting (consuming) every page load.  Not very efficient or smart and probably going to exceed my API limit or make the webservice owners mad.  So instead of fetching directly from a controller action, I have a helper / job / method (some layer) that  has the chance to cache the data a little bit.  Let’s also say that I don’t care too much about the real-time-ness of the data.

Now what I’ve done in the past is simply store the attributes from the weather service in a table and refresh the data every so often.  For example, the weather service might look like this:

```
Weather for 90210 (example primary key)
-----------------------------
Zip Name: Beverly Hills
Current Temperature: 90
Last Temp: 89
Humidity: 0
... etc.
```

So in this case, I would create columns for each attribute and store them when I fetch from the webservice.  I could have an expiring rails action (page caching) to do the refresh or I could do a background job.

This simple approach works well except if the webservice has a large list of attributes (say 1000).  Now I’m spending a lot of time creating and maintaining DB columns repeating someone else’s attributes that already exist.  What would be great is if I could simply cache the whole response and refer to it as a simple Hash when I need it.  Then I’d have all the attributes cached that the webservice offers for “free” because all the capabilities of the web service would be in my Hash instead of just caching a subset.

To do this, I could maybe fetch the webservice response, serialize it (YAML maybe) and then fetch the serialized object if it exists.  Meh, not great.  Serializing can get weird with special characters.  It’d be really cool if I could just follow a memcached type model but I don’t think you can store complex objects in memcached right?  I'd also like to limit the amount of software introduced, so a stand-alone proxy layer would be suboptimal imo.

Anyone done something similar or have a name for this?

Comment: Is there a reason why something as simple as extracting the primary key to its column and dumping the whole response in another column won't work?

Comment: Well I wanted to avoid a blob and have something more structured.

Comment: Is there some hidden meaning of the word "blog" I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the API you're hitting is RESTful and respects caching, don't reinvent the wheel. HTTP has caching built into it (see RFC 2616), so try to use it as far as possible. You have two options:

1. Just stick a squid proxy between your app and the API and you're done.
2. Use [Wrest](http://github.com/kaiwren/wrest) - we wrote it to support HTTP 2616 caching and it's the only Ruby HTTP wrapper that I know that does.

If the API doesn't respect caching (most do) then the other advice you've received makes sense. What you actually use to hold your cache (mongodb/memcached/whatever) depend on a bunch of other factors, so really, that depends on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MongoDB (or another JSON datastore) and get the results of the API in JSON, store the results into your mongo collection. Then get the data and attributes that you care about, and ignore the rest.

For your weather API call, you can check to see if that city exists in your mongo collection, and if not get via the API (and then store in mongo).

It would be a modification of the Rails.cache pattern.

Comment: Yeah.  That's a good idea.  Is this what people mean when they say mongo may be a replacement for memcached?

Comment: Depends on how you're using memcached, but yeah, in this case yes. For other forms of data (serialized data and need for very fast operations), I think memcached is still way to go

Comment: You don't need MongoDB to cache a piece of JSON. Any k/v store will do. We use memcached and redis.

Comment: @Matthias I had said "(or another JSON datastore)".... so we're in agreement here

Comment: What I wanted to say is, you don't need any sort of JSON specific datastore. The beauty of key-value stores like Redis or memcached is (and that's unlike MongoDB or other JSON datastores!) that you can store anything in them, not only JSON. From the reply it sounds as if one had to use a datastore that supports the JSON format, which you don't need.